# How to filter and redirect adb logcat output to a file in real-time?

Tags: android, bash, unix, adb, logcat

I'm currently capturing Android logs using the following command:

```
adb logcat > ~/Desktop/logcat.txt
```

After stopping the log capture, I filter the logs with:

```
cat ~/Desktop/logcat.txt | grep "Sync execution" > ~/Desktop/logcatFiltered.txt
```

However, I'd like to combine these steps to filter adb logcat output in real-time and directly save the filtered lines to a file. I tried:

```
adb logcat > ~/Desktop/logcat.txt | grep "Sync execution" > ~/Desktop/logcatFiltered.txt
```

But it results in a blank file. How can I achieve real-time filtering and redirection?

Comment: Your `grep` reads from the pipe,  but `adb` does not feed anything to the pipe, since you redirect its output to `logcat.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `tee`. It copies standard input to standard output, making a copy in given files.

```
adb logcat | tee ~/Desktop/logcat.txt | grep "Sync execution" | tee ~/Desktop/logcatFiltered.txt
```

Comment: thx lemme try it out real quick

Comment: I tried it a couple times, the out file is still blank, I'm using Git Bash on Windows btw

Comment: Try this in your Git Bash: `printf 'ab\ncd\n' | tee full | grep ab | tee filtered`. It shall output `ab` in console. The file `full` shall contain `abcd` and file `filtered` contains `ab`. If this example worked for you, problem must be from your `adb logcat` command. My Git Bash version 4.4.23 BTW.